# SQL code style. Should I use INNER keyword

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've just got into a discussion with my colleague about using or not using `INNER` keyword in sql statement. AFAIK when using `JOIN` inner is default at least for postgresql that we use. But he said that according to "SQL style guide" I should always state `INNER JOIN`. All that I found in postgres docs is that:

> words INNER and OUTER are not required

and I can't find any discussions on the internet. That's why I decided to ask here if anybody is aware about such convention. Thanks

Comment: There are many "SQL style guides". For example, [Kickstarter SQL style guide](https://gist.github.com/fredbenenson/7bb92718e19138c20591#join) does mention such a rule. However, the only important bit about style guides is that the whole team should follow the same one.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` was introduced when outer joins were added to SQL in the 1990s.  Prior to that, there was just `JOIN`.  I rarely use `INNER JOIN` but its use is totally a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ANSI-92 standard](https://docs.actian.com/vector/4.2/index.html#page/SQLLang/ANSI_2fISO_Join_Syntax.htm), `JOIN` is identical to `INNER JOIN`, and both are equivalent:

> join_type
>   Specifies the type of join as one of the following:
>   **INNER**
>   (Default) Specifies an inner join.

Whether you would choose to use `INNER JOIN` or just `JOIN` is probably mostly a matter of code preference.  I personally almost always use `INNER JOIN`, because it lines up with `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, both of which do require a modifier before `JOIN`.

Comment: Let's not forget `CROSS JOIN`. ;-) If in doubt: [*explicit is better than implicit*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)